# Not allowing user to enter duplicate values

Tags: c, loops

I am writing a code to create a database of student in C. This does not allow duplicate Roll numbers. I created a array of structure of which Roll No. is a  part.

This is the code I wrote so far.NOR is the no. of records already in database and temp id the no. of records I am  entering at this moment.
The duplication check for Roll No. works fine first time but not if I re-enter the same value.
Can anybody help me?

```
for(i=*NOR;i<temp+*NOR;i++)     //For loop to enter student details
{
    int j;
    printf("\nFor student %d:\n",i+1);
    printf("\tEnter the roll No.\n");   //Enter Roll No.
    scanf("%d",&s[i].rollNo);
    while(s[i].rollNo<0)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter valid Roll No.\n");
        scanf("%d",&s[i].rollNo);
    }
    if(i>0)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            for(j=0;j<i;j++)    //Validation for duplicate Roll No.
            {
                if(s[i].rollNo==s[j].rollNo)
                {
                    printf("\nPlease don't enter duplicate Roll No.s\n");
                    scanf("%d",&s[i].rollNo);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if(j==i)
                break;
        }

   //Other code
```

}

Comment: If you re-read a value and then continue the J-loop, only checking the latter portion of the array against the newly entered value, then you aren't checking the new value against the first portion of the array.

Comment: All of this `x[idx].member` notation makes my eyes hurt. `->` was invented for a reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, after detecting a duplicate roll number and getting a new value, you need to check that new value against *all* existing values. In other words, you need to go back to the start.

If you change the `continue` to a break`, the check should re-start properly.

```
while(1)
        {
            for(j=0;j<i;j++)    //Validation for duplicate Roll No.
            {
                if(s[i].rollNo==s[j].rollNo)
                {
                    printf("\nPlease don't enter duplicate Roll No.s\n");
                    scanf("%d",&s[i].rollNo);
                    break; // check new rollNo against all other values
                }
            }
            if(j==i)
                break;
        }
```

Note that `break` can break out of a `while` loop as well as a `for` loop. It always breaks out of the *innermost* loop. So the first `break` leaves the `for` loop, and the second one breaks out of the `while`.

Comment: breaking the inner loop did work. But I still have a question, would that have worked if there was no while loop outside.

Comment: If you don't have the `while` loop, the code will detect the first duplicate, but will not check the new value for duplicates. Another way of looking at this, is that the check `if(j==i)break;` is the part of the code that checks to see if you got to the end of the list without finding a duplicate-- and that check is only meaningful in the context of the loop.

Comment: I still have one doubt. Why is adding the line j=0; before the continue; not working?

Comment: The way that the `for` loop works is that when you do `continue` it will immediately execute the `j++` and then check `j<i` and test your new RollNo against `s[1]` and above -- but not `s[0]`. So to make it work you'd need to say `j=-1` which is.... on the "tricky" side, and impossible if `j` is unsigned, which arguably it should be. A better overall algorithm is "while we do not have a valid number, prompt for a number, get a number, and check the number", which is two loops, one inside the other

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you do not get a *hit* the second time, is because, your duplication check does not *rewind* after finding the first hit.

To elaborate, after the below code snippet,

```
            if(s[i].rollNo==s[j].rollNo)
            {
                printf("\nPlease don't enter duplicate Roll No.s\n");
                scanf("%d",&s[i].rollNo);
                continue;
            }
```

your `j` is not set back to 0, it points to the last occurrence where the match was found, and if you `continue`, you are missing that index and all previously covered indexes from the search.

You have to start the lookup from the *beginning*.

Comment: I tried adding the line j=0; before the continue but still it is not working

Comment: @pmg i thought `continue` will affect the _inner_ `for` loop first, does not it?

Comment: @Yash try `break`-ing out of the loop.

Comment: break-ing did work. But I still have a question, would that have worked if there was no while loop outside

Comment: @Yash, nope, because if you break out of the inner loop, there has to someone outside to push you into the loop once again. Only if you complete the entire loop execution and hit the sentinel condition, `i == j`, then only you can break out the outer while, not before that.

Comment: Yes, it is to me.

Comment: I still have one doubt. Why is adding the line j=0; before the continue; not working?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `while(1)` is infinite if you have `i == 1` and `j == 0`.

If I get it right, you don't need your `while(1)` loop, try remove it.

Comment: Initially I did not include it but I don't know what made me include the loop (may be out of frustration).